# How to disable Drag/drop TRichEdit or TRzRichEdit

Tags: delphi, richedit

How to block the drag and drop in TRichEdit? delphi code
I work with Rich edit and having difficulties on blocking the drag and drop feature specially dragging text from outside the form let say comming from IE to my RichEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [RevokeDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692643%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN;

```
uses
  activex;

RevokeDragDrop(RichEdit1.Handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

try changing on key down/ up event setting it to readonly.
onkey down, set it up to richedit1.readonly := false; and then on keyup richedit1.readonly := true; it works.. it evern disbled the paste features